# How to take direct inputs in char pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *string1;
    scanf("%s",string1);
    printf("\n\nstring 1 is %s\n",string1);
}
```

whenever I run this program it takes the input, but then stops working.
How do I take direct inputs in char pointers in C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for `string1`.

You can do it using `malloc()` function this way:

```
 size_t string_size = 16;
 char *string1 = (char*)malloc(string_size * sizeof(char));
```

This, the length of provided string should not exceed 15 characters.

Comment: So this means that we cannot allocate dynamic memory during while entering a string to a char pointer. ?
like, before entering some string the user must specify its length before hand during runtime ?

Comment: In that case you have already declared variable `string1`. In that case please just type  `string1 = (char*)malloc(string_size * sizeof(char));`. And do not forget to free allocated memory by calling `free(string1)` before the end.

Comment: We can dynamically allocate the memory buffer long enough to store the string. Or we can do this statically in char array, as @paladin proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for your string.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string1[100];
    scanf("%s",string1);
    printf("\n\nstring 1 is %s\n",string1);
}
```

PS Strings in C are just arrays of chars, terminated with '\0' (null).